# My website page doesn't work but JS Fiddle code does - JavaScript and HTML quiz

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

That's the code:

```
function pagechange(frompage, topage) {
    var page = document.getElementById('formpage_' + frompage);
    if (!page) return false;
    page.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    page.style.display = 'none';

    page = document.getElementById('formpage_' + topage);
    if (!page) return false;
    page.style.display = 'block';
    page.style.visibility = 'visible';

    return true;
}

var currentShown = "";

function unhide(rad) {
    var id = "answer" + rad.id.replace("-", "");
    var answer = document.getElementById(id);
    if (answer) {
        var current = document.getElementById(currentShown);
        if (current) current.className = "hidden";
        currentShown = id;
        answer.className = "unhidden";
    }
}

var score = 0;

function scoreIncrement() {
    score++;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NSzxN/

Then here's my website page with that code:

http://elearning.easy2dev.com/quiz_template_3.php

When John is clicked it should increment the score by 1 and then show answer boxes underneath, nothing happens but in JS Fiddle it works. It used to work but I seem to have broken it somehow.

Comment: This can be closed as typo/no-repro (as the solution is not likely to help someone else).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would use FireFox with the FireBug extension, you would see this error:

```
illegal character in quiz_t...e_3.php at line 61:
}​
-^
```

Which refers to the following code:

```
function scoreIncrement() {
    score++;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
}​ // <<-- mysterious zero-length character here
</script>
```

Comment: wow, extremely weird as it is, there was honestly no space after the } or after the score;. Nevertheless I took your advice and deleted the } and put it directly after score; so it now looks like score;} and it works. Thank you very much, I do have Firefox and FireBug but prefer Chrome, serves me right.

Comment: @JohnVasiliou thats just a matter of preference. Chrome does also have an [Error Console](https://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html).